# Share to Facebook with Social: text is not included

Tags: swift, facebook, cocoa-touch, share

I have been using the same code to share to Facebook and Twitter from my app.

Twitter works perfectly by adding the text and picture to the post, but when I use the same code for Facebook the image is included, but the text is not.

I dont understand why the image would work, but the text doesn't.

```
 @IBAction func facebookShare(sender: UIButton) {

    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook){
        var shareToFacebook : SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)

        shareToFacebook.setInitialText("Shared from my app.")

        if myImageView != nil{
            shareToFacebook.addImage(myImageView.image)
        }

        self.presentViewController(shareToFacebook, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Facebook account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: It is against Facebook Platform Policy to prefill the message.

Answer (score 0):

I have used your exact same code. It is sharing both image and text.

Comment: I have. WizKid was right about Facebook now allowing automatically populated text.

Comment: You mean now allowing? or not allowing?